# send data to internet and display return value

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

I am currently learning on how to send data to the internet
im using heroku server that holds the data

Right now, I manage to clear a few errors in the http post request.
The problem is that I can't manage to show the returned value as a string in my app.

I always just end up with `No data available`.

[image]

Can someone help?
I am not sure if there's something wrong with the url or the request it self.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: busNearby(),
    );
  }
}

class busNearby extends StatefulWidget {
  const busNearby({super.key});

  @override
  busNearbyState createState() => busNearbyState();
}

class busNearbyState extends State<busNearby> {
  final TextEditingController queryController = TextEditingController();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> dataList = [];
  String busCode = '';
  late BuildContext scaffoldContext;

  Future<http.Response> fetchData(String c) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusService'),

      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body:
        jsonEncode({'bus_stop_id': busCode}),);
    return response;
        
  }

  
  String showFetchedData() {
    if (dataList.isEmpty) {
      return 'No data available.';
    } else {
      // You can format the data as a string here if needed
      String result = '';
      for (var item in dataList) {
        result += 'Service: ${item['service']}, Next Bus: ${item['next bus']}\n';
      }
      return result;
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Data Retrieval Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    busCode = value;
                  });
                },
                controller: queryController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Bus Service Code',

                ),
              ),
            ),
            Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                scaffoldContext = context;
                
                return ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await fetchData(queryController.text);
                      String message = showFetchedData();
                      if (message.isNotEmpty) {
                        // Show the message using a dialog or other UI element
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text('Data Retrieval Result'),
                            content: Text(message),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                child: const Text('OK'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      }, child: const Text('Fetch Data'),
                );},
            ),
            if (dataList.isNotEmpty) // Show fetched data if available
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dataList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final item = dataList[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Service: ${item['service']}'),
                      subtitle: Text('Next Bus: ${item['next bus']}'),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            DataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(label: Text('Service Code')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Location')),
              ],
              rows: const <DataRow>[
                DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('1076')),
                  DataCell(Text('Larkin Terminal')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('1084')),
                  DataCell(Text('Taman Universiti')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('1019')),
                  DataCell(Text('Skudai Prade')),
                ]),
                DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                  DataCell(Text('1052')),
                  DataCell(Text('Opposite Skudai Prade')),
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

return value to show up in an alert box

which will display a the busses that are available based the bus area code that the user insert

example expected output:

Output: return the estimated arrival time of all bus services at a particular bus stop. Absolute time, and relative time, i.e., arriving in 26 min, and 38 mins
[{"route_id":1,"bus_service_no":"7","eta":[{"time":"2020-07-10 15:17:07","relative_time":26},{"time":"2020-07-10 15:29:21","relative_time":38}]}]

Comment: dataList is not assigned.

Comment: assigned to what please explain..also do you think that the printing format is correct for the bus display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fetchData(String c)` method is incomplete.
You send an HTTP Request, but do nothing with the response.

It should probably look like this

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchData(String c) async {
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://laravelsyd-fypfinalver.herokuapp.com/getBusService'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'bus_stop_id': busCode}),);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         var returnedData = jsonDecode(response.Body) as Map<string,dynamic>;
         // If desired, perform some data validation
         // ...
         dataList = returnedData
     } else {
         // Display error message
         throw Exception('Failed to load data');
     }
    return response;
}
```

This is just a bare-bones implementation. You should probably spend some time to think about data validation, error handling, logging etc.

But the important part is `dataList = returnedData`. You need to assign the loaded data to your state property. Otherwise the app will not now about any new data